# In NHibernate, can I initialize object collections with data already in the session cache?

Tags: nhibernate

Suppose Object A contains a collection of Object B. Let's say it's a one to many (an object B belongs to only one object A)

Now suppose for some reason I already have all the different Object B's in the session cache already.

Now if I went and fetched an object A from the database (giving me an object A with an uninitalized collection of Object B), is there a way I can tell nhibernate to go into the session cache and find all the object B's that belong to this object A and initialize the collection of object B's within the object A I just got?

By initializing the collection, I mean that when I try to use it, it does not need to send any more queries to the database.

I'm using Nhibernate 3.2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no. It doesn't work that way.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Once again Diego, you saved me some time and trouble!

Comment: This answer is not entirely true. It is possible, quite easily tbh, but it's not really NHibernate's desire that you do this. But if for some weird reason you still need this I can tell you how. Using the session cache I've even managed to build undo functionality without the need to rerun queries (I can undo to the database version with a refresh, or undo to the original data I got from the database before I started editing it).

Comment: @TedOnTheNet I'm interested in your solution. Wanna add an answer?

Comment: @TedOnTheNet - I wouldn't mind hearing about your solution, I'm also interested in your undo stuff. Right now we just reload from the database when the user has to undo their changes.